# May one disassemble a Sukkah during Chol Hamoed?

Tags: halacha, sukkah, weather, chol-hamoed

I know from 134:11 in the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch that one may assemble a Sukkah during Chol Hamoed. May one disassemble a Sukkah during Chol Hamoed in order to prevent the Sukkah from being damaged by, say, a hurricane?

Comment: Up for grabs: http://5tjt.com/in-light-of-the-hurricane-can-we-take-down-the-sukkah-on-chol-hamoed/

Comment: Somewhat related as sharing some of the same sources as the Yair Hoffman article linked above http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/64057/dismantling-a-succah-on-chol-hamoed-in-order-to-rebuild-it

Answer (score 1):

The Mishna says succa 22b:

> העושה סוכתו בראש העגלה או בראש הספינה כשרה-.
>    someone who makes his Succah on a wagon or a boat its kosher.          B
>   Rashi::אין הרים מקיפין והרוח שולטת שם ועוקרתה:
>   there are no surrounding hills to block the strong winds.
>   Gemora: מני מתניתין רבי עקיבא היא דתניא העושה סוכתו בראש הספינה רבן גמליאל פוסל ור"ע מכשיר מעשה ברבן גמליאל ור"ע שהיו באין בספינה עמד ר"ע ועשה סוכה בראש הספינה למחר נשבה רוח ועקרתה אמר לו רבן גמליאל עקיבא היכן סוכתך  -
>   In accordance with whose opinion is the mishna? In accordance with the opinion of Rabbi Akiva, as taught in a baraita: In the case of one who builds his sukka at the top of the ship, Rabban Gamliel deems it unfit and Rabbi Akiva deems it fit. Rabban Gamliel and Rabbi Akiva, who were coming on a ship. Rabbi Akiva arose and established a sukka at the top of the ship. The next day the wind blew and uprooted it. Rabban Gamliel said to him: Akiva, where is your sukka?

The gemora explains what the argument is about:.

> אמר אביי דכולי עלמא היכא דאינה יכולה לעמוד ברוח מצויה דיבשה לא כלום היא יכולה לעמוד בשאינה מצויה דיבשה כ"ע לא פליגי דכשרה כי פליגי בדיכולה לעמוד ברוח מצויה דיבשה ואינה יכולה לעמוד (ברוח שאינה מצויה דיבשה) רבן גמליאל סבר סוכה דירת קבע בעינן וכיון דאינה יכולה לעמוד ברוח מצויה דים לא כלום היא ר"ע סבר סוכה דירת עראי בעינן וכיון דיכולה לעמוד ברוח מצויה דיבשה כשרה:.
>   Abaye said: Everyone agrees that in a case where the sukka is unable to withstand a typical land wind, the sukka is invalid as it is not even a temporary residence. If it is able to withstand even a powergul land wind, everyone agrees that the sukka is fit. Where they disagree is in a case where the sukka is able to withstand a typical land wind but is unable to withstand powerful land wind, which is the equivalent of a typical sea wind. Rabban Gamliel holds: In order to fulfill the mitzva of sukka, we require a permanent residence, and since it is not able to withstand powerful land wind, which is like a typical sea wind, it is invalid and is not a sukka at all. Rabbi Akiva holds: In order to fulfill the mitzva of sukka, we require only a temporary residence, and since it is able to withstand a typical land wind, it is fit, (although it is unable to withstand a typical sea wind.)

The Shulchan Aruch O.C 628,2 paskens like Rabbi Akiva.

So we see that Rabbi Akiva didn't take down his Succah even though very strong winds were common place at sea. why not?

Because Rabbi Akiva says in Succah 9a:

> אמר רב ששת משום ר"ע מנין לעצי סוכה שאסורין כל שבעה ת"ל חג הסוכות שבעת ימים לה' -.
>    Rav Sheshes said in the name of rabbi akiva the wood of the succah is forbiddon all 7 days as it says:  “The festival of Sukkot is seven days unto the Lord.”

The shulchan aruch OC 638,1 pasken like this:

> עצי סוכה אסורים כל שמונת ימי החג, בין עצי דפנות בין עצי סכך. (ואפילו קיסם לחצוץ בו שיניו אסור) (מהרי"ל). ואין נאותין מהן לדבר אחר כל שמונת הימים מפני שיום השביעי כולו הסוכה מוקצה עד בין השמשות והואיל והוקצה לבין השמשות של שביעי הוקצה לכל היום- **The wood ( or any material used) of the succah are forbidden to move all 8 days of the festival whether the walls or the sechach, even a toothpick.** One is not allowed to have benefit for anything else even on shmini atzeres (or simchas tora in chutz laaretz*) where there is no longer a use of the succah since it was already prohibited beforehand it remains mukza for the entire 8th day (or ninth in diaspora).

Conclusion: do not take down or move the succah on succos even when expecting the succah to fly away.

Answer (score 0):

I asked my LOR this exact question as we were going away for Shemini Atzeret/Simchat Torah, and rain was expected, and I wanted to protect the schach.

He answered that it was not permissible to take down the Sukkah.  It had to be left up until after Simchat Torah.  It was permissible to take down sukkah decorations, tables, chairs, lights, etc., but the walls and schach had to stay in place.

Comment: so if you are traveling and using a pop up suka, you need to use it as though it is disposable and you need to leave there each one you use?

Comment: @hazoriz: That is a different question from the original posting.  The original posting was about potential damage from weather.

Comment: This Rabbi  to just allow to take down succah decorations without stipulation before Yom Tov contradicts the Mishna brura Orach Chaim 638,2  נוי סוכה בודאי אסורים בלא תנאי מדינא דנוי כסכך הן